# Fake out Typescript's error "Cannot find type definition file for"

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am getting an error that looks like this:

> Cannot find type definition file for 'somemodulehere'

I tried installing `@types/somemodulehere`, but that lead me down a difficult road of conflicting type definitions.

So I am wondering if there is a way to fake out this error.

**Is there some way to fake out this error message and make it go away?  Preferably without having to manually add something to my `node_modules` folder?**

NOTE: This error is coming from a module that merges its code and type definitions in one npm package, so I can't just remove the typings package without losing the code too.

Answer (score 0):

There is but try to avoid it and declare a proper type

Add a file with just

```
declare module "*";
```

As another approach, consider using `--allowJs` compiler flag to consume the JavaScript directly without a declaration.